# .mvn not found in Docker build

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

I'm trying to follow the guide at https://docs.docker.com/language/java/build-images/#create-a-dockerfile-for-java

but the build keeps failing on the line `COPY .mvn/ .mvn` because it cannot find .mvn

My understanding is that it should be finding .mvn bundled in with the eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy which it downloaded in step 1. I don't know how to diagnose whether .mvn is indeed there and/or why it's not able to find it in step 3

#### Full dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy
WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN mvnw dependency:resolve

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

#### Full build output

```
Deploying '<unknown> Dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile'�
Building image�
Preparing build context archive�
[==================================================>]112/112 files
Done

Sending build context to Docker daemon�
[==================================================>] 39.91kB
Done

Step 1/7 : FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy
 ---> 700139b9ad2f
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ff15cfba104
Step 3/7 : COPY .mvn/ .mvn
Error response from daemon: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat .mvn/: file does not exist
Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream
```

Comment: are you sure .mvn is not in .dockerignore?

Comment: Yes as I haven't created a .dockerignore

Comment: Is .mvn supposed to be in my project directory? I have mvnw and mvnw.cmd but no .mvn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .mvn folder it was looking for was supposed to be in the project directory. Running `mvn -N wrapper:wrapper` generated this folder https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper